# How to Aggregate data based on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to aggregate text fields based on date and category columns. 
**And below is how the initial dataset looks like**

> created_at,tweet,category
> 7/29/2021,Great Sunny day for Cricket at London,sports
> 7/29/2021,Great Score put on by England batting,sports
> 7/29/2021,President Made a clear statement,politics
> 7/29/2021,Olympic is to held in Japan,sports
> 7/29/2021,A terrorist attack have killed 10 people,crime
> 7/29/2021,An election is to be kept next year,politics
> 8/29/2021,Srilanka have lost the T20 series,sports
> 8/29/2021,Australia have won the series,sports
> 8/29/2021,Minister have given up his role last monday,politics
> 8/29/2021,President is challenging the opposite leader,politics

**So expected output that I want to get is the below**

> created_at,tweet,category
> 7/29/2021,Great Sunny day for Cricket at London Great Score put on by England batting Olympic is to held in Japan,sports
> 7/29/2021,President Made a clear statement An election is to be kept next year,politics
> 7/29/2021,A terrorist attack have killed 10 people,crime
> 8/29/2021,Srilanka have lost the T20 series Australia have won the series,sports
> 8/29/2021,Minister have given up his role last monday President is challenging the opposite leader,politics

*As per the example I actually want to aggregate tweet text based on date and category. Below is how I used to aggregate without considering category, where I'm in need of aggregation as per the output above.It would be very helpful if anyone can answer this*

```
import pandas as pd

def aggregated():
    tweets = pd.read_csv(r'data_set.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['created_at', 'tweet'])
    df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
    df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)
    df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='1D')).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(set(x)))
    return df


# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(aggregated())
    aggregated().to_csv(r'agg-1.csv',index = True, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = df.groupby(['created_at', 'category'], sort=False, as_index=False)['tweet'] \
        .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))[df.columns]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  created_at                                                                                                    tweet  category
0  7/29/2021  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London Great Score put on by England batting Olympic is to held in Japan    sports
1  7/29/2021                                     President Made a clear statement An election is to be kept next year  politics
2  7/29/2021                                                                 A terrorist attack have killed 10 people     crime
3  8/29/2021                                          Srilanka have lost the T20 series Australia have won the series    sports
4  8/29/2021                 Minister have given up his role last monday President is challenging the opposite leader  politics
```

Answer (score 0):

df is your example
at first tweet column make list with groupby and join list by apply

```
df = df.groupby(["created_at", "category"], as_index=False)["tweet"].agg(lambda x: list(x))
df["tweet"] = df1["tweet"].apply(lambda x:" ".join(x))
df = df.reindex(columns=["created_at", "tweet", "category"])
df
```

output:

```
    created_at  tweet   category
0   7/29/2021   A terrorist attack have killed 10 people    crime
1   7/29/2021   President Made a clear statement An election i...   politics
2   7/29/2021   Great Sunny day for Cricket at London Great Sc...   sports
3   8/29/2021   Minister have given up his role last monday Pr...   politics
4   8/29/2021   Srilanka have lost the T20 series Australia ha...   sports
```